# How do you find the limit of this product of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm having trouble understanding this question:

let $f$ : $\mathbb{R}$ → $\mathbb{R}$ be such that $f$($x$) → $0$ as $x$ → $c$, and let $g$ : $\mathbb{R}$ → $\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Show that

$\lim_{x \to c}$ $f$($x$)$g$($x$) = $0$

I understand that if $g$ has a limit that it is easy to use properties of limits to show it is equal to $0$. However, if $g$ does not have a limit, how do I show this is true? Or does $g$ always have a limit since it is bounded? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $g$ doesn't necessarily have a limit, but the boundedness is key. This tells us that there exists $M>0$ such that $|g(x)|<M$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. We want to show that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)g(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$. Use the bound on $g$ and the limit for $f$.

Comment: How do you know there that $M$ is greater than $0$? Couldn't it be less?

Comment: This is just the definition of bounded. And it actually can't be less than zero, since the absolute value function is nonnegative (that is, we can't have the absolute value of something be less than a negative number).

Comment: Ah yes I see that now, just didn't register the absolute value part so that's why I was confused. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with all assumptions you're given in this sort of problem, boundedness is being used to give you some sense of control for $g$.

In this case: we know that $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to c$; that is, $f$ shrinks as its input approaches the point $c$.  So, what could cause the product $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ to *not* shrink?  The only possibility is that $g$ is growing at the same time $f$ is shrinking, and the rate of growth outpaces the rate of shrinking.

However, because $g$ is bounded, we can't possibly be in this extreme situation.

How can you formalize that?

By assumption $g$ is bounded; so, there exists some $M$ such that $\lvert g(x)\rvert\leq M$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then you know that
$$
\lvert f(x)g(x)-0\rvert=\lvert f(x)g(x)\rvert=\lvert f(x)\rvert\cdot\lvert g(x)\rvert\leq M\lvert f(x)\rvert\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

But we know we can make $\lvert f(x)\rvert$ arbitrarily small by choosing $x$ close enough to $c$.

Can you see how to write a proof using this idea?

Comment: Yes I think I understand it now, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$g$ is a bounded function, so there exists $M\in\Bbb R$, such that $|g(x)|<M\ \forall x$.

For $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$, such that $|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{M}\implies |f(x)g(x)|\le\epsilon$.